# it keeps saying my variable inside the function is not defined can someone help me with this

Tags: python, function, variables, return

```
def draw_card():
    randomrd_drawn_int = random.randint(1,20)


    if card_drawn_int == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
        card_drawn =  ['Mechanized Infantry']
    elif card_drawn_int == [13,14,15,16,17]:
        card_drawn = ['STRV 122']
    elif card_drawn_int == [18,19,20]:
        card_drawn = ['JAS 37']

    return card_drawn
print(card_drawn)
```

here is the syntax error by the way

```
NameError: Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [15], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 print(card_drawn)
NameError: name 'card_drawn' is not defined
```

Comment: You defined `card_drawn` in the body of the function definition, which is just that, a definition. You never executed the function. Use `card_drawn = draw_card()` before printing.

Comment: Thank you  i made a somewhat functioning thing

Answer (score 2):

`card_drawn` is defined inside the function `draw_card` inside if cases.

```py
def draw_card():
    randomrd_drawn_int = random.randint(1,20)
    card_drawn = None

    if card_drawn_int == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
        card_drawn =  ['Mechanized Infantry']
    elif card_drawn_int == [13,14,15,16,17]:
        card_drawn = ['STRV 122']
    elif card_drawn_int == [18,19,20]:
        card_drawn = ['JAS 37']

    print(card_drawn)
    return card_drawn
```

I have rewritten the function so it works.

You need to learn about the scope in Python : https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp

Comment: Printing statements inside functions that return values are useful for debugging, but in general you'll want to avoid them in the final version of the program.

Comment: thanks im learning